# How to call localhost "https" server in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to call "https" localhost server from Expo React Native app. But i'm getting "Network Error". How to call https server in React Native?

Initialise baseUrl in React Native =>
`baseUrl = Platform.OS === "ios" ? "https://localhost:1999" : "https://10.0.2.2:1999"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your app in pc and trying to view app in mobile phone, you should not use "localhost" instead

connect to same LAN, hotspot

If on windows -

- goto cmd
- type "ipconfig"
- goto ipv4 address it looks like ("192.168.178.43")
- this is written instead of localhost in mobile
- put : after it and write port number
- your url will look like **192.168.178.43:1999**

if on linux/mac -
-go to bash/fish/zsh
-type "ifconfig"
-do the same as in linux

Comment: I'm developing in PC and viewing the app in PC emulator only.

Comment: I added my CA certificate to both my physical device and emulator, can connect to https://{my-ip}:{port} through chrome but cannot connect to the same through my react native application.

Answer (score 0):

As [Durgesh Maurya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12590798/durgesh-maurya) mentioned above you. should use your computers IP address instead of localhost/10.0... remember to use the correct protocol too in your JS or TS.
Secondly you've got to add your CA to your Android project and follow the steps listed in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CustomTrust)

Make sure to name the CA certificate my_ca **NOT TO** create a directory called my_ca inside the raw folder.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly try typing

```
npm start
```

in your terminal. Then after that it will prompt you with a choice to either run it in an emulator or on web. all you have to do is hit 'w' on your keyboard. That should run it in your default browser.

```
 Starting Metro Bundler
› Metro waiting on [ip]
› Linking is disabled because the client scheme cannot be resolved.

› Press a │ open Android
› Press i │ open iOS simulator
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press d │ show developer tools
› shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

› Press ? │ show all commands
```

just hit 'w' after this console message

Comment: Your answer is not perfect. Please read the question once again. How to connect https localhost server which has SSL certificate. And I'm viewing the app from emulator.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the issue in anyway.